# Sub graph of a graph up to isomorphism?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$, where $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $E=\{ab,ac,ad,cd\}$. Draw all the sub graph of $G$ up to isomorphism.

Here is my attempt:
[image]

Am I right? Are this the only sub graphs of $G$ up to isomorphism?

**Edit:** Thanks to [muaddib](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242554/muaddib). I've come up with the following list 
[image]

That answers my question.

Comment: The two in the lower left look isomorphic to me.  I'm not saying those are the only two that are isomorphic.

Comment: @muddib: Please look at the labels.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a different definition of isomorphism than I am.

Comment: @user226045: They are. $a \def\lr{\leftrightarrow}\lr a$, $b \lr b$, $c\lr d$, $d\lr c$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: If I am supposed to pay attention to the labels then you are using a different definition of isomorphism than me.  Could you add the definition into the problem?  My notion is the same as martini.

Comment: @muaddib: I'm really sorry you are right!

Comment: @muaddib: So what do you suggest? How many non isomorphic sub graphs of $G$ are there?

Comment: @muaddib: How about the edited one?

Comment: look good to me

Comment: There's also (a) $K_3$ and (b) the empty subgraph: no vertices and no edges.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones: Yes $K_3$ should be in the list. And intuitively (b) also makes sense but could you give me any resource about the empty sub graph?

Comment: It's also referred to as the null graph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_graph  although I tend to reserve that name for the graph with no edges.

Comment: In the "final answer" diagram one is missing. It's the one of a triangle with three vertices and with no fourth vetex. It's not in the earlier attempt either. (2,2,2) But I found the question useful so I'm upvoting it. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write up my suggestion here as we aren't supposed to have long discussions in comments.  There are two steps to solving a problem like this for small graphs:

1) List all the subgraphs.  That looks like what you have in your picture.

2) Compare all the pairs of subgraphs to see if they are isomorphic.  As was suggested in the comments, the lower left two are.  In general, you can think of an isomorphism of an undirected graph as follows: can I rearrange the vertices in one graph to another, preserving edges between pairs of vertices, to get the other graph.